# Error "Creating default object from empty value" Laravel update using one-to-one database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one-to-one database. It's Telepon in different table. So, every 'siswa' has one 'telepon' (telephon number). Telepon has 'sometimes' type not 'required'. It can be blank.
But, if it set blank, error "Creating default object from empty value" appears when i do update.

Code in Telepon Model :

```
    class Telepon extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'telepon';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_siswa';
    protected $fillable   = [
        'id_siswa',
        'nomor_telepon',
    ];

    public function siswa() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Siswa', 'id_siswa');
    }
```

Code in Siswa Model for Telepon:

```
public function telepon() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Telepon', 'id_siswa');
}
```

This in Controller for update:

```
public function update(Siswa $siswa, SiswaRequest $request){
        $input = $request->all();

        $siswa->update($input);

        $telepon = $siswa->telepon;
        $telepon->nomor_telepon = $request->input('nomor_telepon');
        $siswa->telepon()->save($telepon);

        $siswa->hobi()->sync($request->input('hobi_siswa'));

        return redirect('siswa');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the null coalesce operator `??` to check for null or create a new model instance:

```
$telepon = $siswa->telepon ?? new Telepon();
```